# jQuery Optimize link "href" selection

Tags: jquery

I'm changing the class of "a" tag according to "href" file type. It works fine. Here's the code:

```
    $('#divComment a[href$=".pdf"]').removeClass().addClass("pdf");
    $('#divComment a[href$=".doc"]').removeClass().addClass("word");
    $('#divComment a[href$=".docx"]').removeClass().addClass("word");
    $('#divComment a[href$=".zip"]').removeClass().addClass("zip");
    $('#divComment a[href$=".jpg"]').removeClass().addClass("image");
    $('#divComment a[href$=".xls"]').removeClass().addClass("excel");
    $('#divComment a[href$=".xlsx"]').removeClass().addClass("excel");
```

How do I optimize this code?

Comment: why are there those empty `removeClass()` calls?

Comment: To remove any previous class.

Comment: OK, just making sure you really need them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by *optimization*, you mean to make the code more concise and maintainable, then you could create a look-up table.

Example:

```
var extensions = {
    '.pdf': 'pdf',
    '.doc': 'word'
    // ...
};

$('#divComment a').each(function() {
    var match = this.href.match(/\..+$/);
    if(match && extensions[match[0]]) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(extensions[match[0]]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var extensions = {
'pdf': 'pdf',
'doc': 'word'
};


$('#divComment a').each(function() {
    var href = this.href;
    var ext = href.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if(extensions[ext]) {
        $(this).addClass(extensions[ext]);
    }
});

});
```

idea from @Felix Kling post..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nLD2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try a switch case on the $('#divComment a').attr('href').